# Java Android - How to make new line have a bullet point in front

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a note feature in my android app. So everytime a new line is created in the EditText field, a bullet point will be in front of it.

So say I typed in:

> Hello
>
> World!

What should be outputted is:

> • Hello
>
> • World!

Currently my code is rather outputting:

> • Hello
>
> •
>
> World!

The idea is so simple the execution has got me buggered!

Any suggestions?

Here is my Java code:

```
   mNote.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        String words = s.toString();
        Integer mPrevWord = mNote.length() - 1;
        Log.d(TAG, "beforeTextChanged: words "+ s);


        if(words.length()==1){
            words = String.format("• %s", s.toString());
            mNote.setText(words);
            mNote.setSelection(words.length());
        }

    }
});

mNote.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

            Log.d(TAG, "onEditorAction: v " + v);
            Log.d(TAG, "onEditorAction:id " + actionId);
            Log.d(TAG, "onEditorAction: event " + event);
            Log.d(TAG, "onEditorAction: mNote input" + mNote);
            String editorWords = String.format("%s %n • ", mNote.getText().toString());
            Log.d(TAG, "onEditorAction: editwords: " + editorWords);
            mNote.setText(editorWords);
            mNote.setSelection(mNote.length());

            return false;

    }

});
```

As well as my XML code:

```
        <!-- Note info -->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/relLayout6"
            android:layout_below="@id/relLayout4"
            android:padding="10dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_note"
                android:id="@+id/ivNote"/>
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivNote"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textAutoCorrect"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:id="@+id/etContacTNote"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This character has encoding, that is used like all the encodings with a backslash, so find what ASCII character it is and write the ASCII instead of the raw value.

Answer (score 0):

FIGURED IT OUT!
Deleted my setOnEditor altogether because it actually didn't register the enter key when using the android keyboard, only the physical keyboard i entered seemed to register.

Worked in the addTextChangedListener to play around with comparing the new words being added. 
Made an array list, and if that arraylist ever breaks into a new line, then a new bullet point is inserted. 
Here is the code!

```
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            String words = s.toString();
            Log.d(TAG, "beforeTextChanged: words "+ s);

            List<String> myWordList = new ArrayList<String>();
            myWordList.add(s.toString());

            Log.d(TAG, "afterTextChanged: myWord " + myWordList);
            char charWord = myWordList.toString().charAt(s.toString().length());

            if(charWord == '\n' && mPreviousKeyStroke != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL){
                words = String.format("%s\u2022 ", s.toString());
                mNote.setText(words);
                mNote.setSelection(words.length());
            }


            if(words.length()==1 && mPreviousKeyStroke != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL
                    && !words.contains("\u2022")){
                words = String.format("\u2022 %s", s.toString());
                mNote.setText(words);
                mNote.setSelection(words.length());
            }


        }
    });
```

Comment: what is mPreviousKeyStroke?